# Adding custom data in Websocket

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, websocket, phpwebsocket

I would like to send the logged in client side username to a websocket script along with the message the client has entered. I need support on implementing another variable- rge username, to be sent with the message. Right now I'm using:https://github.com/Flynsarmy/PHPWebSocket-Chat and the js is

```
Server.send( 'message', text );
```

with Server being the FancyWebSocket.This is sent to:

```
var FancyWebSocket = function(url)
{
    var callbacks = {};
    var ws_url = url;
    var conn;

    this.bind = function(event_name, callback){
        callbacks[event_name] = callbacks[event_name] || [];
        callbacks[event_name].push(callback);
        return this;// chainable
    };

    this.send = function(event_name, event_data){
        this.conn.send( event_data );
        return this;
    };

    this.connect = function() {
        if ( typeof(MozWebSocket) == 'function' )
            this.conn = new MozWebSocket(url);
        else
            this.conn = new WebSocket(url);

        // dispatch to the right handlers
        this.conn.onmessage = function(evt){
            dispatch('message', evt.data);
        };

        this.conn.onclose = function(){dispatch('close',null)}
        this.conn.onopen = function(){dispatch('open',null)}
    };

    this.disconnect = function() {
        this.conn.close();
    };

    var dispatch = function(event_name, message){
        var chain = callbacks[event_name];
        if(typeof chain == 'undefined') return; // no callbacks for this event
        for(var i = 0; i < chain.length; i++){
            chain[i]( message )
        }
    }
};
```

Which is binded to my server.php as:

```
$Server->bind('message', 'wsOnMessage');    
function wsOnMessage($clientID, $message, $messageLength, $binary)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is up to you which content you send. You could for example send it like

```
Server.send("USERNAME|message", text);
```

Then you can extract the USERNAME on the server by splitting the received string at the pipe `|` symbol.